# mutation observer to catch infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mutation-observers

I use this code on facebook

```
var target = document.querySelector('._38vo');

            // create an observer instance
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                console.log(mutations)
                mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                    console.log(mutation);
                });
            });

            // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
            observer.observe(target, {attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true});
```

Where ._38vo is the user's profile. I expect I can use that to detect whether the new item has been loaded or not. But it doesn't work, hmm any clue why?

Comment: The obvious reason is that nothing is being modified under the specified target or the target element is removed and re-added, in which case you need to find the closest parent that is guaranteed to persist.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried the wrapper, nothing happens too.

Comment: @wOxxOm have you tried? It doesn't work.

Comment: @wOxxOm if there's a video playing you will trigger the observer till the video is stopped.